# Draw uml diagrams for website project

Tags: uml

I am done with creating a website project. I am little confused about drawing my uml diagrams. How can I decide what uml diagrams are necessary for my project? Are structural and behavioral modeling necessary?

Comment: See e.g. http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/152997/truly-useful-uml-diagrams and http://www.agilemodeling.com/essays/umlDiagrams.htm and http://www.uml-diagrams.org/index-examples.html (with "web" in the example name). Voting -1 as your question does not show any research effort is too broad and does not fit the Stack Overflow question format http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is dependent on what you do need to describe. Both, structural and behavioral diagrams can be used for website project.
Use class diagram to define individual web sites, structure and relationships, sequence diagram or activity diagram for web sites behavior. Deployment diagram to define what technology is used to implement and where are your sites deployed (web server, java applet, php etc.) See very simple example below:

[image]

[image]

[image]